# How to achieve an "Inheritance" relationship in SQLite database on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design, inheritance, schema

Consider this simple model:

A base Location table:

```
+-------------------------------+
|           Locations           |
+-------------------------------+
|(PK) _id Integer Autoincrement |
|     name Text(100) Not null   |
|     is_in_range Integer       |
+-------------------------------+
```

And more specialized table called WifiLocation:

```
+-------------------------------+
|         wifi_location         |
+-------------------------------+
|     ssid Text(0) Not null     |
|     signal_threshold Real     |
|(PK) _id Integer               |
+-------------------------------+
```

I want that this model will represents a `WifiLocation` inheriting from `BaseLocation`.
So I added a `REFERENCES` clause on the `_id` column of the `wifi_locations` table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE wifi_locations (_id Integer primary key references Locations(_id), ....)
```

I'm trying to achieve a 1:1 relationship between those tables.

When I want to insert a row to the `wifi_locations` table, I first insert the appropriate values (Name, IsInRange) to the `Locations` table, and get back the `rowId`.
Then I insert the rest of the data (ssid) to the `wifi_locations` table along with the rowId as the foreign key.

So the insertion to the Location table is working, and I'm getting back an Id, but when I try to use this Id and insert it to the wifi_locations table, I'm getting an SQL `Constraint violation` error. There are no more details about what exactly went wrong.

Is there anything wrong with my schema? Is there a better way to achieve such modeling?

**EDIT:**

The exact error:

```
06-16 15:56:42.846: E/Database(2038):
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: 
error code 19: constraint failed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create `FOREIGN KEY` in your second table with will reference to `PRIMARY KEY` in Locations table. In SQLite `FOREIGN KEYS` are supported but implicitly not enabled so first you have to enable them.

```
final String ENABLE_FOREIGN_KEYS ="PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON";
db.execSQL(ENABLE_FOREIGN_KEYS);
```

in your `onOpen()` method of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Then your `FOREIGN KEY` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE wifi_location (
   SSID TEXT NOT NULL,
   SIGNAL_THRESHOLD REAL,
   _id INTEGER,  
  FOREIGN KEY(_id) REFERENCES Locations(_id)
);
```

So but this all works since `SQLite version 3.6.19`. For more information have look at [SQLite Foreign Key Support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

Comment: Thank you, still not working though... BTW I'm running on 2.3.3. Do you know of any other reason that might cause that?

Comment: it should works since Android 2.2 Froyo ... so problem is elsewhere. When error is thrown?? maybe you are trying to insert record without unique UID.

Comment: Haha you are right!! There was ANOTHER constraint I violated and that was the SSID TEXT NOT NULL constraint! I accidentally put twice the NAME value instead of the SSID. Thank you!